# Changing $.ajax to $.post

Tags: jquery, sql, ajax, post

what i am trying to do is send a variable named num (numerical value) to a page named javas.php and then that value is displayed in a class on another php page, its quite complicated to understand, i know, but any help is appreciated. I need this to be as the value of num forms the basis of a sql query therefore the result needs to be posted to php, furthermore, the value of num is used to get the record of the row number "num".

```
$(".eventer button[name=lol]").click(function() { 
    console.log('clicked'); 
    thisBtn = $(this); 
    parent = $(this).parent(); 
    num = parent.data('num'); 
    id = parent.data('id'); 

    if(typeof num != 'number'){ 
        num = 0; 
    } 
    $(this).attr('disabled', true); 

    $.ajax({ 
        url: 'javas.php', 
        data: "num="+ ( num + 1 ) +"&id="+id, 
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('Ajax success'); 
            parent.data('num', ++num); 
            parent.next('.status').html(num); 
            thisBtn.attr('disabled', false); // reset 
        } 
    }); 

    console.log('-- end'); 
});
```

This is what i have so far.
Any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.post('javas.php', { num: (num + 1), id: id }, function(data)  {
    console.log('Ajax success'); 
    parent.data('num', ++num); 
    parent.next('.status').html(num); 
    thisBtn.attr('disabled', false); // reset 
});
```

Comment: @foshoeiyyy, well, I don't have the source code of this javas.php in front of me, nor a jsfiddle that would allow me to reproduce your scenario. So I would recommend you using a debugging tool such as FireBug and try to see where the problem might be. Checkout at the values of the different variables, look at the exact AJAX request being sent, debug your server side script, ... I am sure you will be able to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: <?php 

  $lol =  $_POST['num'];
  
  echo " $lol haha lol cakes";
  

?>

Comment: @foshoeiyyy, looks like the `num` variable is not correctly defined in your javascript. What's its value before sending the request? Oh an by the way you haven't mentioned what this button that you are subscribing to the click event is. If it is a form submit button you might also need to cancel the default action by returning false from the click callback.

Comment: it doesnt have one, this is the first time (In the script) i declare it

Comment: If you don't set `id` and `num` before the call, they will give you an error, and the `post` will never get sent.  Play around with [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UGhRP/).